# QT designer ScrollArea and Layout will change th position of widgets

Tags: qt, layout, pyqt5, designer

I am new to PyQT. I want to creat a scrollable interface but the left side bars in fix position. I've been trying to add with container to make sure the distance between widgets won't change when I resize the window. But still not able to manage it.

Am I doing the wrong way? At the left side I want to but a list of menu buttons with fix position and right side I want to add information to put in later on. If I want to but it in the way I want without layouts, than I can not use scroll bar when labels get out the window. But if I put everything in layout. The distance inbetween will change when I resize the window. Is there a way to set absolute position in QT designer but still manage to have scroll bar?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1014</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background: #B1B479;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea_2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Ignored">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
       <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustIgnored</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="widgetResizable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignTrailing</set>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_2">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>1762</width>
         <height>622</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>0</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
        <property name="sizeConstraint">
         <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
        </property>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>600</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>200</width>
            <height>600</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeIncrement">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="acceptDrops">
           <bool>false</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="statusTip">
           <string comment="1"/>
          </property>
          <property name="layoutDirection">
           <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShape">
           <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="frameShadow">
           <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
          </property>
          <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
           <property name="sizeConstraint">
            <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
           </property>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="FileInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>File Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="PartyInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Party Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="ContainInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Container Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="DocuInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Document Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="LinksetInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Linkset Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="LinksInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Links Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="LinkEleInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>LinkElement Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="LinkIDInfo_Button">
             <property name="minimumSize">
              <size>
               <width>150</width>
               <height>50</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="font">
              <font>
               <family>Arial</family>
               <pointsize>10</pointsize>
              </font>
             </property>
             <property name="cursor">
              <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
             </property>
             <property name="mouseTracking">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border: 2px solid #4B88A2;
border-radius: 15px;
}

QPushButton:hover{
            background: #4B88A2;
            color: white;
}</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>LinkIdentifier Info</string>
             </property>
             <property name="iconSize">
              <size>
               <width>16</width>
               <height>16</height>
              </size>
             </property>
             <property name="checkable">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
             <property name="default">
              <bool>false</bool>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
            <item>
             <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
                <property name="minimumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>150</width>
                  <height>300</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="maximumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>16777215</width>
                  <height>500</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>TextLabel</string>
                </property>
                <property name="alignment">
                 <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
                </property>
                <property name="margin">
                 <number>0</number>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_10">
                <property name="minimumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>300</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeIncrement">
                 <size>
                  <width>0</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>TextLabel</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_9">
                <property name="minimumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>300</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeIncrement">
                 <size>
                  <width>0</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>TextLabel</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_8">
                <property name="minimumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>300</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeIncrement">
                 <size>
                  <width>0</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>TextLabel</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_11">
                <property name="minimumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>300</width>
                  <height>300</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="sizeIncrement">
                 <size>
                  <width>0</width>
                  <height>0</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>TextLabel</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
                <property name="minimumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>150</width>
                  <height>300</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="maximumSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>16777215</width>
                  <height>500</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>TextLabel</string>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </widget>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2"/>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: If you want the buttons always on the left, why did you put them inside the scroll area?

Comment: So If I resize the window to smaller than the menu buttons. Shouldn't I need a scroll?

Comment: Try to set content margins of layout

Comment: I think I've kind of figured out. So when I resize in the designer window the widgets will change. But if I set to preview or open in python the position will not change. It's weird and quitr confusing.....

Comment: @MichaelLin To what "resizing widgets" are you referring to? Are you talking about the buttons? Besides, making widgets adapt their sizes has absolutely *nothing* to do with adding them to a scroll area. Please read more about how [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) work. And also avoid changing the [size policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) of widgets if you don't know how it works